# MySQL faceted search/navigation facet counts

Tags: mysql, rdbms, facet, faceted-search

Yeah, another question like this.. And it's an EAV thing for bonus pain. I'm sorry.

**Before you ask:**

- No, Solr/Elastic Search is a not an option.
- No, the Filter Groups and Filters aren't define-able.
- No, the existing answers don't seem to apply. I've been at it for days..

**Problem Statement:**
How can I write a query that:

- Keeps all the Filters, even those with a 0 product count
- Change the count per Filter to show how many products have the current filter set.

In words I think I need to:

> When Filters are applied, get all the FilterGroups and Filters. Get
>   a count for each Filter of how many products have the currently
>   applied Filters and this one.

The closest I could get was:

```
SELECT 
    fg.Title, 
    f.Title, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(pf1.ProductsID))
FROM 
    Products_Filters pf1
JOIN 
    Products_Filters pf2 ON pf1.ProductsID = pf2.ProductsID
JOIN 
    Filter f on f.ID = pf2.FilterID
JOIN 
    FilterGroup fg on fg.ID = pf2.FilterGroupID
WHER 
    pf1.FilterID = 1
GROUP BY 
    fg.Title, f.Title
```

Results in:

[image]

That shows what the counts for the still applicable Filters are with a Filter of `Lexus` applied.

It's the reverse of what I want but I could work with it. I can't figure out how to make that work with more than 1 Filter applied however.

### The tables:

**FilterGroup table:**

[image]

**Filter table:**

[image]

**Products_Filters table:**

[image]

### Data presented differently:

**By Product** number in parenthesis is the Filter.ID

P.ID = 1
Cars: Lexus (1), Toyota (3)
Colour: Silver (20)
Wheels: HS203 (19)

P.ID = 2
Cars: Lexus (1)
Colour: Green (6)
Wheels: VSXX (17), HS203 (19)

P.ID = 3
Cars: Ferrari (2)
Colour: Green (6)
Wheels:  M1R (18)

P.ID = 4
Cars: Ferrari (2)
Colour: Black (5)
Wheels:

P.ID = 5
Cars: Nissan (14)
Colour: Silver (20)
Wheels:  XD9 (16)

P.ID = 6
Cars: Nissan (14)
Colour: White (4), Black (5)
Wheels:  VSXX (17)

**By Filter**
Lexus: P1, P2
Ferrari: P3, P4
Toyota: P1
Nissan: P6

Black: P4, P6
Green: P3
Silver: P1, P2, P5
White: P6

HS203: P1
M1R: P3
VSXX: P2, P6
XD9: P5

### Example results

Selecting a `Lexus` should result in the Filter counts changing to:

[image]

Selecting `Lexus` and `Silver` should result in the Filter counts changing to:

[image]

Selecting `Silver` should result in the Filter counts changing to:

[image]

## Extra info that may be useful

### Queries for getting products and Filters

**Getting Products:**

```
SELECT 
    Products.* 
FROM 
    Products 
INNER JOIN 
    Products_Filters ON Products_Filters.ProductsID = Products.ID 
WHERE 
    (Products.ProductListPagesID = 6) 
    AND 
    (
        ((Products_Filters.FilterID IN (1))) 
        OR 
        ((Products_Filters.FilterID IN (19)))
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    Products.ID 
HAVING 
    (COUNT(Products.ID) = 2) 
ORDER BY 
    Products.Title ASC
```

That works fine. NB: this is built in an ORM.

**Initial Filters** (no Filters applied):

```
SELECT 
    FilterGroup.Title AS FilterGroupTitle, 
    Filter.Title AS FilterTitle, 
    COUNT(Products_Filters.ProductsID) AS Count
FROM 
    ProductListPage_FilterGroups 
LEFT JOIN 
    FilterGroup ON FilterGroup.ID = ProductListPage_FilterGroups.FilterGroupID
LEFT JOIN 
    Filter ON Filter.FilterGroupsID = FilterGroup.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    Products_Filters ON Products_Filters.FilterID = Filter.ID
WHERE 
    (ProductListPage_FilterGroups.ProductListPageID = 6)
GROUP BY 
    Filter.ID,  
    FilterGroup.Title, 
    Filter.Title, 
ORDER BY 
    FilterGroup.Title, 
    Filter.Title
```

Results in:

[image]

If there's any info I'm missing please let me know. I'm a noob at asking questions.

## Update.

I got a bit closer with :

```
SELECT 
    Filter.ID, 
    Filter.Title AS FilterTitle, 
    FilterGroup.Title AS FilterGroupTitle, 
    COUNT(Products_Filters.ProductsID) AS Count
FROM 
    ProductListPage_FilterGroups 
LEFT JOIN 
    FilterGroup ON FilterGroup.ID = ProductListPage_FilterGroups.FilterGroupID
LEFT JOIN 
    Filter ON Filter.FilterGroupsID = FilterGroup.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    Products_Filters ON Products_Filters.FilterID = Filter.ID
WHERE 
    ProductListPage_FilterGroups.ProductListPageID = 6
   AND 
   Products_Filters.ProductsID IN 
   (
        1,3,5,6
        /*SELECT 
           p.ID
        FROM 
            Products p
        INNER JOIN 
            Products_Filters pf ON pf.ProductsID = p.ID
        WHERE 
            p.ProductListPagesID = 6
        AND 
        (
            pf.FilterID IN (20, 5)
        )
        GROUP BY p.ID 
        HAVING COUNT(p.ID) >= 1*/
    )
GROUP BY Filter.ID
```

Results in:

[image]

In case it's not clear, the applied Filters are Silver (20) and Black (5). The results are the Filters and product counts that can be found by using the Filter.

The sub query is commented out as I wouldn't actually run that in there - I'd already have the ID's.

If that could be modified to also return the Filters that had 0 I'd be done.

Comment: You've provided a lot of information, but I don't see a clear problem statement here.  What is your query supposed to be doing?  Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, probably too much info... Edited to hopefully make the question clearer and show more data.